# How to keep pressing certain key for certain amount of time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I am trying to automate android game using python but I end up in a situation where I have to keep pressing CTRL key and use mouse wheel to zoom out.

I installed Pynput and tried this command

```
keyboard.press('a')
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.release('a')
```

But it doesn't keep pressing **a** key for 3 seconds but press only once.

Can anyone pls tell me a simple script, where it will keep pressing CTRL key and use mouse wheel to zoom out?

Comment: What's the system you are using now?

Comment: my system is windows 10. I want to scroll mouse wheel while keep pressing CTRL key. I want to zoom out and zoom in.

Comment: But if you just press ctrl, it would be okay on my PC.

Comment: I am trying to automate a game. To perform certain action i have to zoom out using CTRL and mouse wheel.

Comment: I think if you only using python,it couldn't work well in GAME.Try to use `AutoHotKey`.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking in the wrong way. Just notice key press is working but mouse scroll is not working in the game. pyautogui.scroll(10) only work in application I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the key to be pressed *over and over again* rather than being held down (which is what I think your code above is doing).

You got two options that I know of. The easiest, by far, is to use floats alongside sleep, and do something like this:

```
timer = 0

while timer < 3:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    timer += 0.1
    keyboard.press('a')
```

This will press the 'a' key every 0.1 seconds until 3 seconds is reached.

Otherwise, you *could* import the 'threading' module which lets you run code in paralel, and therefore run a loop *and* a timer simultaneously. This is probably a huge can of worms for what you're trying to do. The code below presses the 'a' key as fast as possible until the three second timer ends, it doesn't exit threads or anything though, which is why this is probably a bad approach:

```
global_timer = 0

def keep_pressing_a():
    while global_timer <= 3:
        keyboard.press('a')

def count_to_three():
    global global_timer
    keep_counting = True
    while keep_counting:
        time.sleep(1)
        global_timer += 1
        if global_timer >= 3:
            keep_counting  = False

threading.Thread(target=count_to_three).start()
threading.Thread(target=something).start()
```

Comment: Not really. I want to scroll mouse wheel while keep pressing CTRL key. More clearly, I want to zoom out and zoom in. my system is windows 10.